# Runtime Error(NZEC) - java/Codechef

Tags: java

I have been attempting the [CLEANUP](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CLEANUP) problem in codechef, however, it is showing NZEC runtime error on the IDE and runtime error when I submit it to the judge.
Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initialize the scanner.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt(); //no. of test cases.
        for (int r = 0; r <= t; r++) {

            int n = sc.nextInt(); //no. of jobs to be done.
            int m = sc.nextInt(); //no.of jobs already completed.

            ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
            //add the no. of jobs to be done
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int x = i + 1;
                al.add(x);
            }
            //remove no. of jobs already done
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                int q = sc.nextInt();
                Integer a = new Integer(q);
                al.remove(a);
            }

            //print jobs to be done by chef
            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i += 2) {
                System.out.println(al.get(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            //print jobs to be done by asst.
            for (int i = 1; i < al.size(); i += 2) {
                System.out.println(al.get(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            al.clear();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Instead of int, use Long.

Comment: This question is entirely unanswerable.  You haven't told us what your program is supposed to do; but you want to know in what way it fails to do it.  You need to be able to describe your problem more concretely if you want to get help on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is kind of a "do my homework for me" - its a question on how to solve a CodeChef practice challenge.

Comment: Thank you for your input..will frame a more answerable question from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the number of testcases. `for(int r=0;r<=t;r++)` . `r` should begin from 1.

This is the reason for `NZEC runtime error`.
Also , your output is not according to format as mentioned in question.

Look at this code :

```
    //print jobs to be done by chef
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i += 2) {
        System.out.println(al.get(i) + " ");
    }
```

`println()` is printing chef tasks in new line.

Similarly ,

```
    //print jobs to be done by asst.
    for (int i = 1; i < al.size(); i += 2) {
        System.out.println(al.get(i) + " ");
    }
```

hence, use only print().

So, this is the final code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initialize the scanner.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt(); //no. of test cases.
        for (int r = 0; r < t; r++) {

            int n = sc.nextInt(); //no. of jobs to be done.
            int m = sc.nextInt(); //no.of jobs already completed.

            ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
            //add the no. of jobs to be done
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int x = i + 1;
                al.add(x);
            }
            //remove no. of jobs already done
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                int q = sc.nextInt();
                Integer a = new Integer(q);
                al.remove(a);
            }

            //print jobs to be done by chef
            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i += 2) {
                System.out.print(al.get(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            //print jobs to be done by asst.
            for (int i = 1; i < al.size(); i += 2) {
                System.out.print(al.get(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            al.clear();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It is working now.Thank You

Comment: please accept the answer if it was helpful